# Objective-C for loop to set variable text value

Tags: objective-c

I have two things that seem should be easy and I am betting they are easy but this is my first Objective-C program ever so its not coming to me easy like it would in my native Perl.
Both examples are pretty much the same but I am thinking since one is using `@synthesize` it may be very different.

Example 1

```
// What Works
@synthesize display0 = _display0;
@synthesize display1 = _display1;
@synthesize display2 = _display2;
@synthesize display3 = _display3;

// What I would like to do:
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    @synthesize display$i = _display$i;
}
```

Example 2

```
// Works
- (IBAction)clearPressed
{
    self.display0.text = @"0";
    self.display1.text = @"0";
    self.display2.text = @"0";
    self.display3.text = @"0";
}

// What I would like to see
- (IBAction)clearPressed
{
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        self.display$i.text = @"0";
    }
}
```

Any help getting me in the right direction would be great!

Comment: Agree with other posters try some kind of structure, array, list.

Answer (score 13):

How about try this if you are using UILabel:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *valueFields;


- (IBAction)clearPressed
{
    for(UILabel *label in valueFields)
    {
        label.text = @"0";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer, as this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @H2CO3 it answers the question the OP was trying to ask: given a bunch of homogenous UI elements, what's the most Cocoa-like way to refer to all of them such that mutating them doesn't require a whole bunch of copy-pasta'd code?

Comment: I have to agree with Dave here, this answers the question and is the most elegant solution to the problem. +1

Answer (score 9):

Just use an IBOutletCollection:

```
@property (strong) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *labels;
```

Then you can loop through it using fast enumeration:

```
UILabel *label;
for (label in labels) {
    label.text = @"0";
}
```

Comment: +1 for this answer, its a great and new thing for me. Thanks @H2CO3

Comment: @Talha No problem. Enjoy using Objective-C!

Comment: @cotugs Why one solution using `IBOutletCollection` is more complicated than another?

Comment: I originally down-voted your answer because @DaveDeLong is right. Our goal is for simple and elegant answers, especially with new developers. Since you have changed your answer, I have changed my vote.

Comment: @rbrown Thanks. The only sane explanation. (Dave is still wrong, though.)

Answer (score 4):

One way would be using `-valueForKey`, which retrieves the value of the property-name passed to it. Combined with `+stringWithFormat` we can do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"display%i",i];
    UILabel *label = [self valueForKey:key];
    label.text = @"";
}
```

But you should consider using an array. If you are creating the labels in interface builder, use an `IBOutletCollection`.

```
//Connect to every label (.h)    
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *displays;

//Use a fast enumeration to clear every label
for (UILabel *label in self.displays) {
    label.text = @"";
}
//Setting one labels text from an array
[(UILabel *) self.displays[numberOfLabel] setText:@"text"];
```

Comment: An even more compact way to set all the labels in the outlet collection would be to simply use KVO on the outlet array. `[self.displays setValue:@"" forKey:@"text"];` But in the end it doesn't matter, and fast enumeration works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an array?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *display;

@synthesize display;

- (IBAction)clearPressed
{
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        [self.display setObject:@"0" atIndexedSubscript:i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for Example 1-- if your the newest version of Xcode than you do not need the @synthesize, it will do it automatically for you

Example 2-- I do not believe what you want to do is possible like that in Objective-C (H2CO3 proved me wrong in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14056058/480415)), but if you would rather have a loop, than I would create a NSMutableArray of your UILabels or UITextFields and simple loop through them using:

```
for(UILabel *lbl in lblArray)
{
    lbl.text = @"0";
}
```

Or you could iterate through your UIViews subviews and do it that way:

```
for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)view;
        lbl.text = @"0";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible, indeed. Objective-C is a highly dynamic language, and the runtime does everything.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yeah I just checked out your post-- I did not know that could be done

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the responses, this gives me something to build on!

Answer (score 0):

Use Key Value Observing

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
     [self setValue:@"0" forKeyPath:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"display%i", i]];
}
```